# Laravel database query returns wrong values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So in my database I have table called "`records`", which contains approximately 1k entries. This table contains such fields as "id", "`title`", "`date_finished`", "`category_id`", "`user_id`" and some more.

"`date_finished`" by default is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, but user can change it to current timestamp. And so, in this table approximately the half has default `date_finished` and another half has custom.

In my HTML I have `input` with `type="month"` which sends year and month to the controller in format like "2016-10".

And I need to get only those entries that have either default `date_finished` property or `date_finished` with month and year received from input.

In the beginning of my controller I wrote that

```
$record_query =  DB::table('records');
```

Then, I need some additional options to be used, so I have two arrays — $users and $categories containing some ids. Then, I do

```
$record_query = $record_query
       ->where(function($q) use ($users){ $q->whereIn('records.user_id', $users); })
       ->orWhere(function($q) use ($categories){                
            $q->whereIn('records.category_id', $categories);
        });
```

And after that I have about 700 entries left from 1k.

**And here is the part where the problem is.**

To get only those entries that meet the requirements mentioned above, I do

```
$month = Input::get('month');
$record_query = $record_query->where(function($w) use($month){
      $w->where('records.date_finished','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
      ->orWhere(function($q) use ($month){                
            $q->where('records.date_finished','!=','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
           ->whereBetween('records.date_finished',array(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($month)), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($month.'+1 month'))));
       });
});
```

And after this modification I get some 300 entries that do not meet those requirements. The array I get the end contains some random entries with default `date_finished` and custom `date_finished` that has nothing common with one I send from input.

When I run the same query directly in SQL, I get correct results.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Suggestion: when mysql shows a datetime like `0000-00-00 00:00:00` it means that it is NULL so try using `WHERE date_finished IS NOT NULL` or maybe use `IS NULL` depending on what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like

```
$date = Carbon::createFromDate(null, $month, null);

$record_query = $record_query->where(function($w) use($date){
    $w->where('records.date_finished','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
        ->orWhere(function($q) use ($date){                
            $q->whereBetween('records.date_finished', [$date->toDateString(), $date->addMonth()->toDateString()])));
   });
});
```